# Is there a pythonic way to assign values based on conditions in pandas in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I am currently having trouble with the following issue: I've got a dataframe that consists of different users, applications and notifications records. For each user and application, I need to check whether a notification has been interacted with -- if the user interacted with the corresponding application after receiving the notification. If so, I assign the timestamp of the  first application interaction to all preceeding notification(s) of that application.

The input looks like the following:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,'a','notification',1], [1,'b','notification',2], [1,'b','app',3], 
                            [1,'a','notification',4], [1,'a','app',5], [1,'a','notification',6],
                            [1,'a','app',7], [2,'a','notification',8]]), columns=['user','app', 'type', 'timestamp'])
```

The result should look like this:

```python
df_result = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,'a','notification',1,5], [1,'b','notification',2,3], [1,'b','app',3,0], 
                            [1,'a','notification',4,5], [1,'a','app',5,0], [1,'a','notification',6,7],
                            [1,'a','app',7,0], [2,'a','notification',8,0]]), columns=['user','app', 'type', 'timestamp','interacted'])
```

Currently, I have the code running using the following code:

```python
def compute_groups(x):
    x.loc[(x.type == "app"), "tmp"] = 1
    x["sequence_id"] = x.tmp.cumsum()
    x.sequence_id = x.sequence_id.shift(1, fill_value=0)
    x = x.drop('tmp', axis=1)
    return x


def compute_interactions(x):
    x['interacted'] = x[x.type == 'app']['timestamp']
    x.interacted.bfill(inplace=True)
    return x

df["tmp"] = 0
df = df.groupby(['user','app']).apply(compute_groups)
df = df.groupby(['user','app','sequence_id']).apply(compute_interactions)
df['interacted'] = df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x.type == 'app' else x.interacted, axis=1)
```

The current code seems to work but is running quite long. The input dataframe has over 600k records. I assume there is something more pythonic way to do this, potentially with groupby and shift combined.

Comment: yes, do some research, read the documentation of pandas dataframe, google 'dataframe  find on condition' for example

Comment: I already looked it up and found nothing useful...

Comment: Well, as far as I know, the apply() with lambda is one of the fastest ways. also grouping looks good, take a look at this, maybe it helps, regarding performance: https://towardsdatascience.com/different-ways-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-performance-comparison-dc0d5dcef8fe

Comment: I am currently keeping this code and try to come up with a faster one later on. Thanks for providing the link.